# Troubleshooting labeling points on a residuals vs. fitted plot

Tags: r, plot, identify

In R, I have a residuals vs. fitted plot and am trying to label the points. Specifically there are two points at the extreme end of the plot's x-axis that I want to identify. I've looked at hat values and Cook's distances; combined, these flag four different points, but that doesn't narrow down which two of the four (if any) are the ones I'm focused on in my residuals plot.

General format of my code:

```
mod1 <- lm(y.variable ~ x.variable, data = dataframe)
summary(mod1)
plot(fitted(mod1), residuals(mod1))
abline(h = 0)
```

I've tried:

```
identify(fitted(mod1), residuals(mod1), labels=name, plot=TRUE)
```

to which I get:

```
'warning: no point within 0.25 inches'
```

even when I'm definitely clicking within the point. Also when I hit escape, I get `integer(0)`.

Comment: Seems indeed buggish to me, assuming you using RStudio, can you make the preview plotting window narrower with the mouse? Interestingly, it works better then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot the labels directly:

```
plot(fitted(mod1), residuals(mod1), type = "n")
text(fitted(mod1), residuals(mod1), labels = names)
```

assuming `names` is an appropriate vector of point labels (can be `1:length(fitted(mod1))`.

Comment: I think they rather want to label just a certain, visually identified subgroup of points, though.

Comment: This works perfect- thank you! And sorry I wasn't clear about 'names' in OG post- on my end it was just a row index.